# Webpack Error: Module parse failed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I am relatively new to using webpack. The question I have is, When I run `./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d` I am getting thrown an error. I was wondering can anyone help me and advise me as to where I might be going wrong. 
The error is below as follows:

```
`ERROR in ./src/components/App.js
 Module parse failed: /Users/danielmccord/webpack-
 demo/src/components/App.js Unexpected token (8:2)
 You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
 | 
 | const App = () => (
 |   <div>
 |     <AddTodo />
 |     <VisibleTodoList />
 @ ./src/client/app/index.js 17:11-44`
```

Webpack config

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');
var config = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js?/,
            include: APP_DIR,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }]
    },
};
module.exports = config;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add your webpack config code

Comment: which version of webpack are you using

Comment: I am using verison 3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Although you have specified the loader for your webpack config, you have not specified the ES6 preset and your test regex is incorrect, Change your config to

```
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: APP_DIR,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: [{
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
                        presets: ["stage-0","es2015","react"],
                        plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
                    }
        }]  
    }]

},
```

P.S. Make sure you install the presets and plugins with

```
npm install -S babel-plugin-transform-class-properties babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage-0
```

Comment: I changed my config to the what is above, but I have now got a new error saying "
Error: 'output.filename' is required, either in config file or as --output-filename"? But i have a bundle.js file already? Confused!

Comment: Yeah got it thanks.Removed the error but got a new one saying "ERROR in ./src/client/app/index.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-class-properties" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/Users/danielmccord/webpack-demo/src/client/app..."

Comment: Thanks for the help, but once I did all that, it has thrown me back the original error I had at the start. Any suggestions?